# Server Hosted at Data center Internal IP address on hyper-v guest OS

Tags: hyper-v, virtual-machines, nat, windows-server-2012, rras

I have a hosted server that’s located at a data center that I pay for monthly (www.liquidweb.com). The server is running windows server 2012 standard. The server is used to host a SQL database and a FTP server (no website). The server has an external IP address assigned to it from the data center. I access the resources of the machine through that IP address (SQL and FTP). I have recently decided that I need an additional machine for other purposes so I am attempting to setup a VM using hyper-v. The guest OS is also Win Server 2012 standard. Installation went perfect, but the only issue I am having is getting the correct network settings. I do not need this VM to have an externally facing IP address (an internal 10.x.x.x address is fine as long as the VM has internet access and the ability to talk to the host machine through standard windows networking)
I followed the instructions in step 5 in the link below to setup RRAS with NAT:
http://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/show/1161-hosted-windows-servers-hyper-v-and-creating-a-secure-network

Everything works perfectly however I can no longer access the resources of the host computer through its external IP address. I can still remote to it via Teamviewer (and I’m sure RDP although I have not tested) and both machines host and guest have complete access to the internet, but now when I try to access SQL or FTP via the external IP address I can no longer reach it. I hope it’s just some silly setting I forgot to check but it’s got me knocking my head against the wall. Also, I should mention that networking is not my strong suit. 
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: After configuring the _new_ VM your _old_ vm is no longer accessable through its original IP?

Comment: no, I only have one VM. I have a host OS and 1 VM that I am trying to create. My host is no longer accessible throuhg the external IP once I setup the NAT with RRAS

Comment: there is a checkbox to share selected network, if selected you cut your legs out from underneath and you'll need the hoster to fix this.

Comment: I am not sure if that checkbox exists or not, but I did not lose connectivity to the host (that was my biggest concern when setting this up though). I had to undo the entire setup because this is a production machine and I needed the connectivity, but I can reconfigure it back to where it was in about 5 minutes. Its strange because it still has full internet access, its just inbound traffic appears not to be able to find it.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of NAT you should have to consider External Net and Add Live IP address direct to machine. This will resolve your problem.

Comment: I could do that, but ideally I'd rather it be internal for three reason. (not sure if all or any of my reasons are valid though)
1. security purposes - i dont need it to be externally faceing
2. Cost: you have to pay a monthly fee for additional IP’s although its only a few bucks
3. Data transfer speed between guest and host. If I use an external IP wont all the data that moves between the two machines have to go through the data centers router vs just going directly from host to guest?